# Why has Community edited a negatively marked answer to a closed question?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

This question showed in my feed today:

[Algorithm to calculate sum of points for groups with varying member count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349894/algorithm-to-calculate-sum-of-points-for-groups-with-varying-member-count)

It showed because although it's an old question (closed), Community had edited [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39350341/1583) to it, by adding 4 words...

[image]

If community is not a real person then I presume some funky AI added it - but why?

Why edit a closed, answered question by adding a comment to a negatively voted answer when the comment does not actually make any difference to the answer?

Comment: It was an edit suggested by a user that was not logged in and approved by the person who made the post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15508556

Comment: Ah ok, I guess it's not explicitly explained like that hence my misunderstanding - thanks